# Ruby- Selenium: Could we find an element by its 2 properties in parallel at the same time?

Tags: html, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

First of all, we have an element like that:

"<"id="select_a_boundary" class="dataset_select2">Homes name<>

As we know, when find an element by selenium in ruby based on a property we use the method:

@driver.find_element(:id, "select_a_boundary") or @driver.find_element(class,"dataset_select2")

Could anyone know the way to find this element by both properties id and class in selenium ruby? Because sometimes there is other element has the same id property or same class property. **And assume that we are not allowed to use Xpath** to combine it, how could we deal with it? Thanks for all suggestion.

Comment: why you are thinking you will not be allowed to use `xpath` ? You can use it. It is built in `web-driver`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
     <div id="select_a_boundary" class="dataset_select2">Homes name</div>
```

Selenium code:

```ruby
@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[@id = 'select_a_boundary' and @class = 'dataset_select2']") 
@driver.find_element(:css, "div[id=select_a_boundary][class=dataset_select2]")
@driver.find_element(:css, "#select_a_boundary.dataset_select2")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as I said above if we are not allowed to use Xpath how can we find it?

Comment: When I tried @driver.find_element(:id=>"select_a_boundary", :class=>"dataset_select2") It worked, but it seem to it just cared the first locator. When the first locator is true it will pass, although the second locator is wrong. And when first locator is wrong it will fail. For example, @driver.find_element(:id=>"select_a_boundary", :abcd=>"just test"), it will return pass

Comment: @Popo Yes.. Don't use it.. if you have problem.. with `xpath`,which you should not to.. use `CSS selectors`.. These are good tool for such situations..

Comment: because the requirement of my assignment does not prefer to use xpath and css, so it is reason why I must find other way to do that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Popo Sorry I am not aware of any other techniques.. :((

Comment: It's ok Priti, thanks you so much. I will try to find other way. :)

Comment: @Popo while you will be having `:id` then you can get the element directly,as it is unique.. I don't know why you are thinking to use `id` and `class` altogether.. :))

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you cannot use Xpath/CSS try collecting all the similar searches to list and then you can use the collected list items to pin point your search.